# AngularJS+Flask Failed to instantiate module

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I have been nearly everywhere looking for this, but please do forgive me if I ended up missing something. 
Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PDFHandle</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='custom.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {% raw %}
        <div ng-app="uploadApp" ng-controller="UploadController as uc">
            <div ng-repeat="choice in uc.choices">
                <input value="{{choice.value}}" />
            </div>
            <button ng-click="uc.addChoice()">Add</button>
        </div>
    {% endraw %}
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my AngularJS script:

```
var Try = angular.module("uploadApp", [])
.controller("UploadController", function UploadController() {
    this.choices = [{id: "choice1", value:"Hello"}];
    this.addChoice = function() {
        return this.choices.push({id:"choice"+(this.choices.length+1), value:"Hello Again"});
    };
})
```

The problem I'm facing is this (showing in Chrome's developer tools):

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uploadApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'uploadApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I can run this by normally linking it with an HTML file just fine, it's just when I try to use it with a flask rendered HTML that it doesn't work. I have also tried this with other Angular IDEs and it's working fine in them as well. Like I said, just doesn't work with flask.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your controller like this

```
var Try = angular.module("uploadApp", []);
Try.controller("UploadController", function() {
    this.choices = [{id: "choice1", value:"Hello"}];
    this.addChoice = function() {
       this.choices.push({id:"choice"+(this.choices.length+1), value:"Hello Again"});
    };
})
```

Comment: Nope, this didn't work either.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The exact same as the one mentioned in the question. It's a bit huge so I can't really put it all here, but it's basically stating all the lines in angular.js where it encountered the error.

Comment: I think the problem lies in your sript tag which you are trying to laod dynamically. Check your browser if that script is being loaded or not

Comment: Oh boy. The script is getting loaded, but it isn't the right script. The custom.js in the static dir is not the one that's getting loaded, but rather it's loading a crazily outdated custom.js. I'm going to clear caches and try this again, and I'll let you know whether it worked or not. This is going to get chosen one way or another.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks a lot for catching it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
angular.module("uploadApp", [])
.controller("UploadController", function UploadController() {
    this.choices = [{id: "choice1", value:"Hello"}];
    this.addChoice = function() {
        return this.choices.push({id:"choice"+(this.choices.length+1), value:"Hello Again"});
    };
})
```

Comment: Same issue. This is what I was originally doing, but switched it to try out other stuff.

Comment: try wrapping entire html with {% raw %}